# Android - Keep soft keyboard while using external keyboard

Tags: android, bluetooth, keyboard

I am trying to have android tablets and phones keep soft keyboard while using external keyboard. We have a Bluetooth barcode scanner that disables the soft keyboard when paired with the device. Is there any way to allow two keyboards so they can type and scan without switching the input each time?

Specifically we are using Samsung Tab3's but looking for a solution that works on all androids on the entire device. More specifically in the web browser. We will be writing a JQuery mobile web app.